# Applying WAN Changes to Juniper Chassis Cluster

Tags: firewall, network, juniper, wan, juniper-srx

I have a Juniper SRX 340 in a chassis cluster state.

I am looking to change the WAN IPs used by the firewalls as the ISPs will change. I have GE interfaces that have sub interfaces within them 1,2,20,4092-4093 and 32767. The internet providers are running on 4092 and 4093 sub interfaces (or VLANs), but I can't seem to find a place where I can edit the IP on the interfaces. The editing button is disabled?

The IPs appear only in the "Chassis Cluster" section, but it doesn't appear that I can change it in this area either. I would like to change the IP for WAN without breaking the cluster settings.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cluster srx firewalls interfaces are reth0, reth1, reth2 etc.

the untrust / management interface will be reth0 usually.
& reth1 interface will have the vlans, you should be able to see the isp ip on the reth1 interface logical units

the "show interface terse" on cli will list something like below

```
ge-0/0/4.557            up    up   aenet    --> reth1.557
ge-0/0/4.933            up    up   aenet    --> reth1.933
ge-0/0/4.1222           up    up   aenet    --> reth1.1222
ge-0/0/4.1268           up    up   aenet    --> reth1.1268
ge-0/0/4.32767          up    up   aenet    --> reth1.32767
............
ge-5/0/4.557            up    up   aenet    --> reth1.557
ge-5/0/4.933            up    up   aenet    --> reth1.933
ge-5/0/4.1222           up    up   aenet    --> reth1.1222
ge-5/0/4.1268           up    up   aenet    --> reth1.1268
ge-5/0/4.32767          up    up   aenet    --> reth1.32767
.........
reth1                   up    up
reth1.557               up    up   inet     76.x.x.x/29  
                                            76.x.x.x/29
reth1.933               up    up   inet     10.x.x.x29    
reth1.1222              up    up   inet     10.x.x.x/29   
reth1.1268              up    up   inet     10.x.x.x/24   
reth1.32767             up    up
```

if the show interface terse output shows similar to above output, then
so to change 4092 & 4093 vlan ips, you will have to do

```
conf t
delete interfaces reth1 unit 4092 family inet address old ip/2x
delete interfaces reth1 unit 4093 family inet address old ip/2x
set interfaces reth1 unit 4092 family inet address new/2x
set interfaces reth1 unit 4093 family inet address new/2x
commit
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a newer SRX, and J-Web has changed substantially in newer versions, but I believe that IP Address configuration is under `Interfaces / Ports` (eg: completely separated from the chassis cluster configuration).

It may be that your GE interfaces are bound to RETH interfaces and so can't be edited directly, but you can't break a chassis cluster by changing IP addresses.